# Makefile is working really weird

Tags: makefile

I wrote a very simple Makefile like this:

```
CXX = g++
CFLAG = -g -I../include
XNNLIB = ../src/cpuxnn.a
PROGS = testcpu

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.c $(XNNLIB)
(this is a tab here)$(CXX) $(CFLAG) -o $@ $^
```

and "make" starts g++ like this:

> g++      testcpu.cpp   -o testcpu

What happened to the CFLAG var???? and why the command is in such a mess order?
I searched and researched but no answer. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written a pattern rule for `.c` files, but make is finding a `.cpp` file, so it compiles it using the built-in rules for compiling C++.

You need to change your pattern rule to use `%.cpp` not `%.c`

It's conventional to use variables called `CFLAGS` (for C) and `CXXFLAGS` (for C++) not `CFLAG`

Comment: The default rules (like the one being used accidentally here) use `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` by default for exactly that purpose.